# How to pass an implementation of an interface as a variable in a method in Java?

Tags: java, interface

We have an interface `Math`.

We have two implementations of `Math` (say they are called `Math1` and `Math2`). A small part of the project is being able to switch between the two.

In a class (say its called `ClassName`) we were provided by our instructor, we have:

```
public static int evaluate(Math impl)
```

I have:

```
ClassName.evaluate(Math1);
```

It says it cannot find symbol. I tried putting it in quotes, but then that's a string. I've tried to google things to try, but I'm not finding anything that helps (maybe I'm just searching for the wrong thing). The files are in the same package.

How do I pass the interface implementation?

Comment: I had seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859589/passing-interface-class-as-a-parameter-in-java  I'm not quite sure what its saying, so if thats the answer, could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the class name instead of a class instance.

Try this:

```
// Evaluate with Math1.
Math m1 = new Math1();
ClassName.evaluate(m1);

// Evaluate with Math2.
Math m2 = new Math2();
ClassName.evaluate(m2);
```